# Looking for responsive js carousel

Tags: javascript, responsive-design, fullscreen, carousel, fluid

I am trying to find a carousel like in: http://whiteshoe.ferragamo.com but simpler.
All I need is a responsive full page carousel with items that have a description and link on "active" mode, and the others just title and as they are inactive, they look darker or greyish.

Ive tried this one http://caroufredsel.dev7studios.com but don't know how to add the inactive/active states, and the responsive: true doesn't re size my images.
Thanks :)

Comment: _"I am trying to build a carousel"_ - Are you actually trying to build one, or are you asking for a recommendation of an existing library that does it for you?

Comment: I am actually not a programmer (I'm more like a css geek), so...Id like a library that can make it easier...I could do some modifications but not that much, heh. :3 thanks!

Comment: Ok, edited my question because I didn't notice my stupidity in it when I posted it. Now it is clear, I'm looking for a carousel library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so...

I found that the js just added iline css properties, so I added some css to make it responsive (without resizing my images, which works by now for my needs).
CaroFredSel adds some classes to the code you write so all I needed to add was the width:100% !important property to make it work.

For the js part, I had to add a highlight to the current so I added this code and it works:

```
function highlight( items ) {
    items.filter(":eq(1)").css({
        opacity : 1
    });
    return items;
}
function unhighlight( items ) {
    items.css({
        opacity : .3
    });
    return items;
}
```

And then, after the default properties of size and general things:

```
scroll: {
items:1,
onBefore: function( data ) {
        unhighlight( data.items.old );
    },
    onAfter : function( data ) {
        highlight( data.items.visible );
    },
},

auto: false,
prev: {
    button: "#prev",
    key: "left",
    onBefore: function( data ) {
            unhighlight( data.items.old );
        },
        onAfter : function( data ) {
            highlight( data.items.visible );
        }
},
next: {
    button: "#next",
    key: "right",
    onBefore: function( data ) {
            unhighlight( data.items.old );
        },
        onAfter : function( data ) {
            highlight( data.items.visible );
        }
},
```

And at the end:

```
highlight( unhighlight( $j("#f-carousel > *") ) );
```

});

I will add more highlighting things, and texts on the 'onafter' but I think this covers it all.
Thanks and hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

It's funny, but it seems that the responsive of this responsive caroussel doesn't work in my browser (on the demo page)... There are a lot of responsive jquery caroussel anyway, you'll find one on google...

Comment: yeah.. but I'm starting to notice that the responsiveness is js but it just overrides the css, so I am tweaking and accomplishing part of my goal...still want to add changing states thou..

Comment: So good luck with caroufredsel. If it's a bit hard, post your code, we can help maybe. If it's really hard, think about using another carousel...

Answer (score 0):

This is a good one. Very minimal, nice code, and it's responsive and cross-browser friendly.

http://unslider.com/